# If entire element is in view make element position:fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this code that alerts on click whether the entire element is in view. I'm looking to create a sidebar along the same lines in that when the sidebar is in full view I need it to become position:fixed to the bottom of the page else be position:relative. (minus the on click I just want it to happen when scrolling).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8x4Zd/109/)

I'm not great with JS so not sure if I'm thinking on the right lines? Could this sort of thing be easily adapted for what I need.

```
$(document).click(function() {
   var win = $(window);
   var el = $('#tester');
   var winPos = win.scrollTop() + win.height();
   var elPos = el.offset().top + el.height();

   alert(winPos > elPos);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So... will the end result look & work something like this? http://codepen.io/Guilh/pen/JLKbn (as a sidebar)

Comment: Sort of except I need the sidebar to stick to the bottom when the entire sidebar is in view. Is that easily achievable? The best example I have of what I'm trying to achieve is Zara's navigation side menu http://www.zara.com/uk/en/sale/woman/outerwear-c436392.html

Comment: If you click on 'Women' in the menu so that it opens and the sidebar is longer than the viewport and then you scroll you will see what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If you have function that shows the menu and another one that hides it, just use jQuery...

```
function show(){
  menu.show();
  menu.css("position", "fixed");
}
funtion hide(){
  menu.hide();
  menu.css("position", "relative");
}
```